# how do i get intent extra bundle value in different tabs of tab activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

In my application there are some values in list view and on clicking the list Item am getting values from database and passing it using intent in an array list

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
            s = mDbHelper.fetchDetails(appName);
            // s.add(app_formno);
            /*
             * for(int i =0; i<Data.size();i++){ s.add(Data.get(position));
             * System.out.println(Data.get(position)+"*****"+i); }
             */
            prefEditor.putBoolean("gotobundle", true);
            prefEditor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(ListViewDetails.this,
                    ApplicationManagement.class).putExtra("list", s));
```

I am getting the array list in e bundle which is in Tab widget(TAB 1).

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    settings = getSharedPreferences("LandTshare", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefEditor = settings.edit();

    boolean bool = settings.getBoolean("gotobundle", false);
    if (bool == true) {
        Bundle b = getParent().getIntent().getExtras();
        // ArrayList<String> bundlevalue = new ArrayList<String>();
        bundlevalue = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (b != null) {
            bundlevalue = b.getStringArrayList("list");
```

this code prints the respective values in tab 1 but when i go to tab 2 the value in the bundle is empty and my application force closes..
Below is the code in TAB 2

```
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume();
    boolean bool = settings.getBoolean("gotobundle", false);
    if(bool == true){
            if (Applicant.bundlevalue.size() > 124 == true){
            for (int i = 125; i <= 146; i++)
                System.out.println(Applicant.bundlevalue.get(i));

            if (Applicant.bundlevalue.get(125).equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                rg_existin1.check(R.id.rYes);
            } else {
                rg_existin1.check(R.id.rNo);
            }
```

what is the issue here?? i cant seem to figure out!
Please help!

Comment: did u got NullPointer exception in ur logcat

Comment: yes i got Null pointer @Sam

Comment: it is name of the activity in first tab @Sam